# as3 tabbing to next form field starts on 2nd line

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a simple form I created in flash and I set it up so you can tab from one field to the next.  The problem is when I tab to one of the fields, a multiline textbox, it starts on the second line of that field. If I click on the textfield it goes to the 1st line.

ANy idea how I can remedy this?

The code is pretty simple:

_styleLibForm.tabChildren = true;

```
_styleLibForm.first_name.tabIndex = 1;

                _styleLibForm.first_name.tabEnabled = true;
                _styleLibForm.first_name.focusRect = true;

                _styleLibForm.city.tabIndex = 2;
                _styleLibForm.city.tabEnabled = true;
                _styleLibForm.city.focusRect = true;

                _styleLibForm.description.tabIndex = 3;
                _styleLibForm.description.tabEnabled = true;
                _styleLibForm.description.focusRect = true;

                _styleLibForm.email.tabIndex = 4;
                _styleLibForm.email.tabEnabled = true;
                _styleLibForm.email.focusRect = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428871/how-to-change-tab-ordering-in-flex-actionscript-sdk-3-5/4439019#4439019) 
 and did you try making your lowest `tabIndex = 2`?

Comment: the problem I am having is not that it doesn't tab, it just goes to the wrong line when it does tab to a multiline field. Instead of starting at the top of the textfield, line 1, it starts at line 2.

Comment: @pfunc : how did you create it? is there a chance that you hit enter while it was focused?

Comment: It's created in the flash ide and no, I didn't hit enter.

Comment: @pfunc : did you try to remove it from the stage and create by code?