# How to tab vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, flex4.5

I am working in Flex and trying to get a sparks datagrid to tab vertically instead of horizontally.

```
var hBox:HBox = new HBox();
var templateDataGrid:spark.components.DataGrid = new spark.components.DataGrid();
templateDataGrid.dataProvider = dataGridList;
templateDataGrid.columns = columnHeaders;
templateDataGrid.sortableColumns = false;
templateDataGrid.editable = true;
hBox.addElement(templateDataGrid);
```

Have a pretty simple as3 implementation that I am rendering inside a HBox.

Here is a full working example from the API, I am writing my grid in as3 not mxml, but i can translate.

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

<s:Panel title="Spark DataGrid Control Example which demonstrates the variableRowHeight and rowHeight properties"
         width="75%" height="75%" 
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">

    <s:controlBarContent>
        <s:HGroup verticalAlign="baseline">
            <s:CheckBox label="variableRowHeight={dataGrid.variableRowHeight}" selected="@{dataGrid.variableRowHeight}"/>
            <s:Label text="      "/> <!-- blank space -->
            <s:HSlider minimum="12" maximum="120" value="@{dataGrid.grid.rowHeight}"/>
            <s:Label text="rowHeight={dataGrid.grid.rowHeight}"/>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:controlBarContent>    

    <s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" left="5" right="5" top="5" bottom="5" editable="true">
        <s:ArrayCollection>
            <s:DataItem key="1000" name="Abrasive" price="100.11" call="false"/>
            <s:DataItem key="1001" name="Brush" price="110.01" call="true"/>
            <s:DataItem key="1002" name="Clamp" price="120.02" call="false"/>
            <s:DataItem key="1003" name="Drill" price="130.03" call="true"/>
            <s:DataItem key="1004" name="Epoxy" price="140.04" call="false"/>
            <s:DataItem key="1005" name="File" price="150.05" call="true"/>
            <s:DataItem key="1006" name="Gouge" price="160.06" call="false"/>
            <s:DataItem key="1007" name="Hook" price="170.07" call="true"/>
            <s:DataItem key="1008" name="Ink" price="180.08" call="false"/>
            <s:DataItem key="1009" name="Jack" price="190.09" call="true"/>             
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </s:DataGrid>
</s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

The grid example can be seen in the [api here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html) if you want to see the grid, and see than when you tab it goes horizontally. I want it to go vertically!

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428871/how-to-change-tab-ordering-in-flex-actionscript-sdk-3-5 might be helpful

Comment: @www0z0k As shown in the example, `s:Datagrid` does not present its rows and columns as DisplayObjects, but instead interfaces with the arraycollection. So that link isn't directy relevant for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far. It works in that when the person releases the tab key, it looks at where they are, and goes to a different location. (in my case down one.) The built in tab navigation happens on on `KEY_DOWN`, and this occurs on the `KEY_UP`. So the selected item bounces around which may not be the best. This works where for `GridSelectionMode.SINGLE_CELL`.

```
myGrid.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, selectionChangingHandler);

private function selectionChangingHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.TAB){
        var selectedCell:CellPosition = event.currentTarget.selectedCell;
        var columnLength = event.currentTarget.grid.columns.length;
        var rowLength = event.currentTarget.grid.dataProvider.length;
        var columnIndex:Number = selectedCell.columnIndex;
        var rowIndex:Number = selectedCell.rowIndex+1;

        if(rowLength == rowIndex){
            if(columnIndex == columnLength-1){
                columnIndex = 0;
                rowIndex = 0;
            }else{
                columnIndex = columnIndex+1;
                rowIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        var success:Boolean = event.currentTarget.startItemEditorSession(rowIndex,columnIndex);
        event.currentTarget.setSelectedCell(rowIndex,columnIndex);
    }
}
```